# Pooled Particle Effect Stops Rendering after player dies and screen is recreated

Tags: java, libgdx, ashley

I have an issue in a game I'm developing where the particle effects work for the first instance of the game. After the player dies a new instance of the main screen is started *(which creates the controllers, Ashley engine and Ashley systems)* and the particle effects no longer appear. I believe it may have something to do with me using a pooled particle effect inside a pooled component but I an unsure. Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Below is most of the code regarding the particle effects:

**ParticleEffectComponent** (contains all particle related data)

```
    public class ParticleEffectComponent implements Component,Poolable{
    public PooledEffect particleEffect; // stores effect
    public boolean isattached = false; // whether it's attached to object
    public float xOffset = 0; // offset from attached object
    public float yOffset = 0; // offset from attached object
    public float timeTilDeath = 1f; // add a 1 second delay
    public boolean isDead = false; // dead flag
    public Body attachedBody; // box2dbody that this is attached to if any

    @Override
    public void reset() {
        particleEffect.free(); // free the pooled effect 
        particleEffect = null; // empty this component's particle effect
        xOffset = 0;
        yOffset = 0;
        isattached = false;
        isDead = false;
        attachedBody = null;
        timeTilDeath = 0.5f;
    }
}
```

**ParticleEffectSystem** (rendering system for particles)

```
    public class ParticleEffectSystem extends IteratingSystem{

    private static final boolean shouldRender = true; // render toggle flag

    private Array<Entity> renderQueue; // array of particle entities to render
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ParticleEffectSystem(SpriteBatch sb, OrthographicCamera cam) {
        super(Family.all(ParticleEffectComponent.class).get());
        renderQueue = new Array<Entity>();
        batch = sb;
        camera = cam;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        super.update(deltaTime);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.enableBlending();
        // Render PE
        if(shouldRender){
            batch.begin();
            for (Entity entity : renderQueue) {
                ParticleEffectComponent pec = Mapper.peCom.get(entity);
                pec.particleEffect.draw(batch,deltaTime);
            }
            batch.end();
        }
        renderQueue.clear();
    }


    @Override
    protected void processEntity(Entity entity, float deltaTime) {
        ParticleEffectComponent pec = Mapper.peCom.get(entity);
        if(pec.isDead){ // set to true when attached object is destroyed
            pec.timeTilDeath -= deltaTime;  // decrement time 
        }

         // Move PE if attached
        if(pec.isattached){
            pec.particleEffect.setPosition(
                    pec.attachedBody.getPosition().x + pec.xOffset,
                    pec.attachedBody.getPosition().y + pec.yOffset);
        }
         // free PE if completed
        if(pec.particleEffect.isComplete() || pec.timeTilDeath <= 0){
            getEngine().removeEntity(entity);
        }else{
            renderQueue.add(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

**ParticleEffectManager** (manages loading of particles and particle pools)

```
    public class ParticleEffectManager {
    // DEFINE constants for particleEffects
    public static final int SMOKE = 0;
    public static final int WATER = 1;
    public static final int FIRE = 2;

    // create intmaps for effects and pools
    private IntMap<ParticleEffect> partyEffects;
    private IntMap<ParticleEffectPool> partyEffectPool;

    /**
     *  Particle Effect Manager for controlling creating pools and dispensing particle effects
     */
    public ParticleEffectManager(){
        partyEffects = new IntMap<ParticleEffect>();
        partyEffectPool = new IntMap<ParticleEffectPool>();
    }

    /** Create a particle effect pool for type  with default values (scale 1, pool init capacity 5, max capacity 20)
     * @param type int id of particle effect
     * @param party the particle effect
     */
    public void addParticleEffect(int type, ParticleEffect party){
        addParticleEffect(type,party,1);
    }

    /** Create a particle effect pool for type with scale and default pool sizes
     * @param type int id of particle effect
     * @param party the particle effect
     * @param scale The particle effect scale
     */
    public void addParticleEffect(int type, ParticleEffect party, float scale ){
        addParticleEffect(type,party,scale,5,20);

    }

    /** Create a particle effect pool for type
     * @param type int id of particle effect
     * @param party the particle effect
     * @param scale The particle effect scale
     * @param startCapacity pool initial capacity
     * @param maxCapacity pool max capacity
     */
    public void addParticleEffect(int type, ParticleEffect party, float scale, int startCapacity, int maxCapacity){
        party.scaleEffect(scale);
        partyEffects.put(type, party);
        partyEffectPool.put(type,new ParticleEffectPool(party,startCapacity,maxCapacity));

    }

    /**
     *  Get a particle effect of type type
     * @param type the type to get
     * @return The pooled particle effect
     */
    public PooledEffect getPooledParticleEffect(int type){
        return partyEffectPool.get(type).obtain();
    }
}
```

**LevelFactory** (creates objects for the level)

```
    //... more methods ...
    public Entity createBullet(float x, float y, float xVel, float yVel, BulletComponent.Owner own){
        System.out.println("Making bullet"+x+":"+y+":"+xVel+":"+yVel);
        Entity entity = engine.createEntity();
        B2dBodyComponent b2dbody = engine.createComponent(B2dBodyComponent.class);
        //.. more components ..
        BulletComponent bul = engine.createComponent(BulletComponent.class);

        bul.owner = own;

        b2dbody.body = bodyFactory.makeCirclePolyBody(x,y,0.5f, BodyFactory.STONE, BodyType.DynamicBody,true);
        //.. make other components etc ...
        animCom.animations.put(0, anim);

        type.type = TypeComponent.BULLET;
        b2dbody.body.setUserData(entity);
        bul.xVel = xVel;
        bul.yVel = yVel;

        //attach party to bullet
        bul.particleEffect = makeParticleEffect(ParticleEffectManager.FIRE,b2dbody);

        entity.add(bul);
        //.. add more components etc ...
        entity.add(type);   

        engine.addEntity(entity);



        return entity;
    }

    /**
     * Make particle effect at xy
     * @param x 
     * @param y
     * @return the Particle Effect Entity
     */
    public Entity makeParticleEffect(int type, float x, float y){
        Entity entPE = engine.createEntity();
        ParticleEffectComponent pec = engine.createComponent(ParticleEffectComponent.class);
        pec.particleEffect = pem.getPooledParticleEffect(type);
        pec.particleEffect.setPosition(x, y);
        entPE.add(pec);
        engine.addEntity(entPE);
        return entPE;
    }

    /** Attache particle effect to body from body component
     * @param type the type of particle effect to show
     * @param b2dbody the bodycomponent with the body to attach to
     * @return the Particle Effect Entity
     */
    public Entity makeParticleEffect(int type, B2dBodyComponent b2dbody){
        return makeParticleEffect(type,b2dbody,0,0);
    }

    /**
     * Attache particle effect to body from body component with offsets
     * @param type the type of particle effect to show
     * @param b2dbody the bodycomponent with the body to attach to
     * @param xo x offset
     * @param yo y offset
     * @return the Particle Effect Entity
     */
    public Entity makeParticleEffect(int type, B2dBodyComponent b2dbody, float xo, float yo){
        Entity entPE = engine.createEntity();
        ParticleEffectComponent pec = engine.createComponent(ParticleEffectComponent.class);
        pec.particleEffect = pem.getPooledParticleEffect(type);
        pec.particleEffect.setPosition(b2dbody.body.getPosition().x, b2dbody.body.getPosition().y);
        pec.particleEffect.getEmitters().first().setAttached(true); //manually attach for testing
        pec.xOffset = xo;
        pec.yOffset = yo;
        pec.isattached = true;
        pec.particleEffect.getEmitters().first().setContinuous(true);
        pec.attachedBody = b2dbody.body;
        entPE.add(pec);
        engine.addEntity(entPE);
        return entPE;
    }
//... more methods etc ...
```

Comment: Well the easiest way to check would be to remove all code inside of the `reset` method. Have you tried that to make sure that's the source of your problems?

Comment: I commented out all the reset code and the problem still persists.